# Differentiation of Algebraic Functions (Involving Rectangles)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a weird question for me. It looks like this:

"$\it{ABCD}$ is a rectangle, and a straight line $\it{APQ}$ cuts $\it{BC}$ in $\it{P}$ and $\it{DC}$ extended in $\it{Q}$. Find $\it{BP}$ so that the sum of the areas of two triangles $\it{ABP}$ and $\it{PCQ}$ will be a minimum."

On how it was described, I came up with this figure.

[image: Is this the figure being described?]

I don't know where to start though. How do you answer the question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to some affinity, we may assume that $ABCD$ is a unit square without loss of generality, since affine maps preserve ratios of areas. Then by assuming that $CP=y\in(0,1)$ we get that twice the area of $ABP$ is given by $1-y$ and twice the area of $CPQ$ is given by $y\cdot\frac{y}{1-y}$. The minimum of

$$ f(y) = 1-y+\frac{y^2}{1-y} $$
is attained at $y=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}$, hence the solution is given by $BP=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}BC$.